# TEST wifi network using SSID/password without connecting to it

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am a react native developer, with little experience in native android development. I have done a lot of research about this but with little to no answers.

I am developing for an IoT device, and I need to send it the network credentials to which it to connect. The user should select their wifi network from the app, enter its password and I should check the combination for correctness without actually attempting a connection... Is this possible via the Android API in any way?

Thanks in advance.